# Wordpress insert shortcode into menu item

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svg, shortcode

I have such a problem. In **functions.php**  I have such code:

```
function Svg_Path($attr) {
    $a = shortcode_atts(array(
        'path' => 'Some text'
    ), $attr);
    $svg = '<svg class="menu-item-icon"><use xlink:href=' . get_template_directory_uri(). '/img/svg/sprite.svg' . $a["path"] . '></use></svg>';
    return $svg;
}
add_shortcode( 'SvgPath', 'Svg_Path' );
```

Normally, I can use in pageBuilder this

```
<div>[SvgPath path='#logo__skype']</div>
```

And the result will be the displayed Skype Icon. But when I try to insert this shortcode into Appearence>Menu>Link text I get the shortcode as plain text

[Where do I try to input my shortcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2YyP.jpg)

So can you help me wwith this, so I can recieve skype logo from svg sprite in menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. The code will parse your shortcode and show you the shortcode content. It'll only work on frontend.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title, $item_id ) {
    if ( 'nav_menu_item' === get_post_type( $item_id ) ) {
        return do_shortcode( $title );
    }
    return $title;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm quite new to PHP. But how to connect this code with my shortcode?

Comment: Add the code to your `functions.php` file and everything will work as you expected.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: As of 2020, this randomly causes sites to crash as WP tries to build the menu. Can't figure out exactly what causes it, sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it definitely doesn't.

Comment: Maybe the menu has lots of items for the shortcode has an expensive DB call. You can try caching the menu. This might help https://gist.github.com/bjornjohansen/5fa3aa830b7ce7b8244e17cc8924eb64

Comment: Didn't work on my site. Shortcodes just display as if they're text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the updated FontAwesome to create this and add this into your menu instead?

https://fontawesome.com/icons/skype?style=brands may help you out.

Comment: The point is that I have a big menu, even several big menus. So each menu item has it's own icon. In order to make less reqests I make one sprite from all those svgs. I can paste this icon inline via <svg><use></use></svg>. But I don't like the way it looks like in admin menu and want to use shortcode

Comment: but you'll be making one request which would be the FontAwesome library, and then calling each item within the Menu's section for example <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>. FontAwesome would be doing the same idea are your sprite is without haveing to call anyshortcodes. I would say the other way you can do this is by creating classes for each icon and just calling the class within the menu item rather than code but the FontAwesome option would be easier to implement. Either way could work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But with this shortcode, it's like the painful issue for me. I have spent today several hours trying to understand what is wrong. So I am searching for solutions with shortcode. I will implement FontAwsome but I still wish to know how do do it with the shortcode.

Comment: The main thing for me would be to try and make it the easiest possible way for you to add/update icons and from my own personal expereicne, using FontAwesome has always been the route I have gone. I have never used shortcodes within the Menu's admin section but can see they would probably work in the same sort of way as FontAwesome would but that way seems a far more convoluted way rather than using <i class="fab fa-skype"></i>. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: The post upper solves really all that I want. But I also like your solution will try to implement it in next site.